# What replaces amoeba gem beyond Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, amoeba-gem

It appears that the Amoeba gem is no longer being maintained since late 2017 and the readme only claims compatibility with Rails thru version 5.1

Has anybody figured a best path for deep copies, including associations, for Rails 5.2 and beyond?

Comment: You could drop a note to the core members of the gem via email/twitter and ask them about this. I usually find the devs to be pretty responsive :)

Comment: Thanks, @bsvin33t, but the core members have all ababndoned the project.

Comment: I think you have some good news :D check this out! https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba/pull/83

Comment: Yes. I had emailed Alex Simonov who said he would be merging PR's. I guess maybe I prompted him to go look and merge. Yay!

Comment: Nice :D . I really love how awesome the ruby community is!